# Where to find packages names and versions for RedHat?

Tags: linux, package, redhat, rpm

How can I find out whether a specific RedHat release (RHEL4, RHEL5...) contains a certain package (or a certain version of a package)? For Debian and Ubuntu, there's packages.debian.org and packages.ubuntu.com; is there a similar web site for RedHat?

Note: I don't want to have to install all the releases just to check some package version :-)

Comment: http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=redhat&pkglist=true&version=rhel-7.2#pkglist

Answer (score 13):

The best you can do, as it seems, is to check the FTP directories of the source packages:

- [RHEL4](http://web.archive.org/web/20190807022012/http://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/4/en/os/i386/SRPMS/)
- [RHEL5](ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/5Server/en/os/SRPMS/)
- [RHEL6](ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/6Server/en/os/SRPMS/)
- [RHEL7](ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/7Server/en/os/SRPMS/)

Keep in mind that RedHat has the habit of patching software to hell and back, so the version number might not have to much in common with the actual release, especially for the kernel.

Comment: The RHEL7 link is broken for me; but looking at the historical CentOS archive at http://vault.centos.org/ appears to be a good replacement. Full example link: http://vault.centos.org/7.4.1708/os/x86_64/Packages/

Answer (score 3):

For starters: http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=redhat has a list of the important versions, but certainly does not list all package versions.

Comment: Actually, distrowatch does have a full list: http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=redhat&pkglist=true&version=rhel-7.2#pkglist

Answer (score 3):

Apparently Red Hat does have such an online package list for its RHEL distros, but it's only accessible for paying Red Hat customers :-(

Btw. similar question (for CentOS): https://serverfault.com/questions/239205/official-online-rpm-package-browser-search-for-centos

Answer (score 2):

Since RedHat and CENTOS are very similar, you may be able to get a decent list from looking at the packages in the CENTOS repository for the corresponding version.  Go to one of the following sites and go to your RedHat / CENTOS version and locate the packages.  The CENTOS versions coincide with the RedHat versions.

http://vault.centos.org/

http://mirrors.centos.org/

For example, for an i386 system with RedHat 6.3 (or CENTOS 6.3), check out the following site: 
http://vault.centos.org/6.3/os/i386/Packages/

I am not guaranteeing it will be a 1 to 1 mapping, but it should be very close.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your yum repositories set, you can use "yum search " to see if it exists, or "yum list" to see all available packages.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Fedora is now working on an online list of packages (PackageDB - see http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Infrastructure/PackageDatabase). The current version is available at https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/ . It doesn't seem to know about all RHEL4/RHEL5 packages, though.

Answer (score 0):

Note: by "browsing" an `rsync://` mirror instead of an `ftp://` mirror you can conveniently filter files using wildcards instead of having to wait minutes to download the massive and comprehensive list of all packages.